# Turnbased gamecenter game: when is persistence needed?

Tags: ios, persistence, game-center, save, multiplayer

I'm working on an ios turnbased game (gamecenter). Question is : when do i have to save the gamedata ? Ofcourse when it's the players turn and the app goes to the background or terminates before the player's move has been passed to the other player, but are there other scenarios in which the gamedata should be saved ?

Answer (score 1):

In general, for any client-server application (game or otherwise), the client should persist the data back to the server whenever the user takes an action that the server needs to know about.

To put it another way, if the user takes an action and the server *never* knowing about it will cause problems, it needs to be persisted.

For example, if the user does X and then their phone explodes, will it be a problem if, when they open the application up on a new phone, X hasn't been done? If the answer is "OMG of course that will be a problem!!!1", then X should be persisted.

In general, I *always* assume that *every* action taken on a client should be persisted to the server if at all possible. This can happen asynchronously when it make sense, but the server's record of the application state is the only thing that *really* matters.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, the only way to persist data on the server while using the turnBased API's of game center (assuming my turn isn't over yet) is to use the following:

```
 [myTurnBasedMatch endTurnWithNextParticipant:me matchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError *error)];
```

that is passing the turn to yourself while updating data. This works fine but all of the other devices that are logged in with the same Game Center account will get a notification saying "It's your turn", anyone knows a way around this?